# Why don't my rectangles show up?

Tags: javascript, html

A simple problem to most of you however I have an issue with my HTML or JavaScript. I am trying to make some rectangles appear when running the code. I am met with the all to familiar blank screen. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/myCanvas.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/rectangles.js">
</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Canvas Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="lessonCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="margin:100px;">
<p>This example requires a browser that supports the <a      href="http://www.w3.org/html/wg/html5/">HTML5</a> canvas feature.</p>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function setupCanvas() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('lessonCanvas');
if (canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    ctx.strokeRect (0.5, 0.5, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillRect (20, 20, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
    ctx.fillRect (50, 50, 100, 100);
    ctx.clearRect (80, 80, 30, 30);
   }
}
```

Any help for a clueless would be appreciated

Comment: What will cause `setupCanvas()` to run?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the edit. As TheSeamau5 and yourself have said I need to call setupCanvas(). Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually call `setupCanvas`

[Here's a codepen showing this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPJvEa). As you can see, I just added one line to your code. I hope this is the result you intended

Comment: Thank you for your help and answer. That is the result that I wanted.